# possible values of $P(A|C)$ when we know that $P(A|B)=P(B|C) = 1/2$

Tags: probability

What are possible values of $P(A|C)$ when we know that $P(A|B)=P(B|C) = \frac12$ ?

It is fairlt difficult for me, and I can't deal with it.  I know conditional probablity and bayesian probablity, however it doesn't help me.  Could you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix $t\in[0,1]$.  We can associate the sets $(A\cup B\cup C)^\complement$, $A\setminus (B\cup C)$, $B\setminus (C\cup A)$, $C\setminus (A\cup B)$, $(B\cap C)\setminus A$, $(C\cap A)\setminus B$, $(A\cap B)\setminus C$, and $A\cap B\cap C$ with the following probabilities: $$0\,,\,\, 0\,,\,\, \frac{t}{3}\,,\,\, \frac{1-t}{3}\,,\,\, \frac{1-t}{3}\,,\,\, \frac{t}{3}\,,\,\, \frac{1-t}{3}\,,\text{ and  }\frac{t}{3}\,,$$ respectively.  Then, $\text{Prob}(A|B)=\text{Prob}(B|C)=\frac{1}{2}$ and $\text{Prob}(A|C)=t$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sample space $\{1,2,3\}$ with all outcomes equally probable.

Calculate $\mathsf P(A\mid B), \mathsf P(B\mid C), \mathsf P(A\mid C)$ for the following senarios:

- $A= \{1\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{2,3\}$
- $A=\{2\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{2,3\}$
- $A=\{2,3\}, B=\{1,2\}, C=\{2,3\}$

Comment: Very clear solution!

Answer (score 0):

One side:

Let $D_1,D_2,D_3,D_4$ be disjoint with $\Pr(D_i)=\frac14$ for $i=1,2,3,4$.

If $A=D_1\cup D_2$, $B=D_2\cup D_3$ and $C=D_3\cup D_4$ then

$\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(B\mid C)=\frac12$ and $\Pr(A\mid C)=0$.

So apparantly there is (apart from the usual $0$) no lower bound for $\Pr(A\mid C)$.

---

Other side.

Let $E_1,E_2,E_3$ be disjoint with $\Pr(E_1)=\Pr(E_2)=\Pr(E_3)=\frac13$.

If $A=C=E_1\cup E_2$ and $B=E_2\cup E_3$ then $\Pr(A\mid B)=\Pr(B\mid C)=\frac12$ and $\Pr(A\mid C)=1$.

So apparantly there is (apart from the usual $1$) no upper bound for $\Pr(A\mid C)$.

---

This is an indication (not a proof) that $\Pr(A\mid C)$ can take any value in $[0,1]$. For a proof see the answer of **Batominovsky**.

To get some hold on situations like this it can help to think of $\Omega$ as disjoint union of the $8$ sets of the form $F\cap G\cap H$ where $F\in\{A,A^c\}$, $G\in\{B,B^c\}$ and $H\in\{C,C^c\}$. If $p_1,\dots,p_8$ denote the probabilities of these sets then $p_1+\cdots+p_8=1$ and all probabilities involved have expressions in the $p_i$.

Answer (score -2):

Hint:
use the Law of total probability,
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability

and consider stochastic independence (if given).
Answer for more information^^

Comment: Could you be more preciesly, please ? We don;t know nothing about independence in this task

Comment: Ok first Bayes $$ P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)} $$ and use $$P(A^C|B)= 1-P(A|B)$$ and then try to use the law of total probability^^

Comment: You need information about the complementary events

Comment: Is link meant be be an answer, or is it something that can only work if more information is given ("you need info about complementary events")? I really don't see the use of this. If no elaboration follows then I will downvote.

Comment: If you want to use the law of total probability it can help to know the probability of  the complementary events maybe there is a better way... downvote if you need to^^